# Pass variables from terraform to arm template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

I am deploying an [ARM](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html) template with Terraform.
We deploy all our Azure infra with Terraform but for AKS there are some preview features which are not in terraform yet so we want to deploy an AKS cluster with an ARM template.
If I create a Log Analytics workspace with TF, how can I pass the workspace id to ARM.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "k8s-test-bram"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "test" {
  name                = "lawtest"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}
```

So here is a snippet of the AKS ARM where I want to enable monitoring and I refer to the workspaceresourceId. But how do I define/declare the parameter to get the id from the workspace that I created with TF

```
        "properties": {
            "kubernetesVersion": "[parameters('kubernetesVersion')]",
            "enableRBAC": "[parameters('EnableRBAC')]",
            "dnsPrefix": "[parameters('DnsPrefix')]",
            "addonProfiles": {
                "httpApplicationRouting": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                omsagent": {
                  "enabled": true,
                  "config": {
                    "logAnalyticsWorkspaceResourceID": "[parameters('workspaceResourceId')]"
                  }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the parameters property of the `azurerm_template_deployment` deployment to pass in parameters:

```
  parameters = {
    "workspaceResourceId" = "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.test.id}"
  }
```

I think it should look more or less like that, [here's](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html) the official doc on this.

Comment: You also need to add the parameter in your arm template:

        "parameters": {
                "workspaceResourceId": {
                "type": "string"
            },

Comment: I thought it would be handy to mention in case anybody else is looking for this question :)